# GA - API Management: Channel Grouping

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to export the 'Channel Grouping Settings' for the Google Analytics properties with the Management API. But I can't find any way to export for all the properties.

Is there any way to export the channel grouping?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**It's not possible**. The channel grouping settings are not part of the resources you can retrieve via the Management API:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference

To elaborate a bit more: Channel settings are view/profile-level resources. Some of these can be retrieved (eg goals, general view settings), but not the channel groupings.